# Opendaylight BORON packet handling

Tags: java, sdn, opendaylight

About this post, Opendaylight BORON packet handling ( Hydrogen's IListenDataPacket class - [Opendaylight BORON packet handling ( Hydrogen's IListenDataPacket class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622720/opendaylight-boron-packet-handling-hydrogens-ilistendatapacket-class) )... 
Someone know what is the parameters received in this methods?

```
public PacketHandler(DataBroker dataBroker, 
                     PacketProcessingService packetProcessor) 
{
    ...
}


public void onPacketReceived(PacketReceived notification) 
{
    ...
}
```

If I would like to use this methods in my own module (i.e., in the `init()` method), what parameters I need to pass?

The method `onPacketReceived`, receive its parametes from MDSAL layer?

Thanks in advance... 
Thanks in advance. Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of `PacketHandler` are :

- `DataBroker dataBroker` : The broker which will give you access to the MD-SAL. It enables you for example to access the controller's registry.
- `PacketProcessingService packetProcessor` : The service which will enable the controller to receive packets sent from the switches and handle them.
  The service is provided in model-flow-service from bundle of openflowplugin, as stated [here](https://yinqingwang.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/how-to-send-raw-packet-from-odls-controller-to-network-datapath/).

The parameter of `onPacketReceived` is :

- `PacketReceived notification` : A notification that there is an incoming packet to the controller, as a `PacketIn` message.

If you want to call these methods and you need to have these parameters so that you can provide them to the methods, you need to know that `dataBroker` can be obtained like this :

```
DataBroker db = session.getSALService(DataBroker.class);
```

where `session` is a `ProviderContext session` provided as input in `onSessionInitiated` of your provider. Also :

```
PacketProcessingService packetProcessor = rpcProviderRegistry.getRpcService(PacketProcessingService.class);
```

where :

```
rpcProviderRegistry = session.getSALService(RpcProviderRegistry.class);
```